# buscar un texto en cualquier columna de una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un proyecto en php html y tal, el tema es que tengo una tabla en mysql como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que intento es tener un buscador para que busque en toda la tabla todos los valores que tengan el mismo texto que busco o parcial, es decir, si busco "nusa" que me muestre la entrada 1 y 2. si busco H que me muestre el 1 y 3 y su busco "2" que me muestre el 1,2y3 (el 1 por que en cumpleaños tiene un 2, el 3 por lo mismo y el 2 por que pet_id es 2...

No se si me explico.

he probado con

```
SELECT pet_id, patient_id,gender FROM pacientes where CONCAT(pet_id, patient_id, gender) like 'nusa';
```

pero sin exito

Comment: Prueba con `line '%nusa%'` o bien algo así:`SELECT pet_id, patient_id,gender FROM pacientes WHERE pet_id like '%nusa%' OR patient_id like '%nusa%' OR gender like '%nusa%'`

Comment: me sirve, lo del %XXX% que es como un selector entrecomillado?

Comment: Documentación: [Pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html). Podés buscarlo como _comodín_ o _wildcard_ (y `%` no es el único que existe, por cierto).